# How to detect non-number of the list?

Tags: python, list

Suppose I have a list as the following:

```
a = ['111', 213, 74, '99', 't', '88', '-74', -74]
```

The list contains number-like string, number and string of the data types.

I consider number-like string can convert number, so it's can see as a number.

This is my method:

```
a = ['111', 213, 74, '99', 't', '88', '-74', -74]

def detect(list_):
    for element in list_:
        try:
            int(element)
        except ValueError:
            return False
    return True

print detect(a)
```

But it looks so lengthy and unreadable, so anyone has better method to detect it?

Additionally, my list contains negative number and negative-number-like string, how do I do?

Comment: It is a bit lengthy but definitly not unreadable. But you should replace `except:` with `except ValueError:` and lift the `try-except` to wrap the `for`loop instead of individual elements

Comment: Although commenting the exception make it more readable, I hope it can be simplified one-line code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For only positive integers:

```
not all(str(s).isdigit() for s in a)
```

For negatives:

```
not all(str(s).strip('-').isdigit() for s in a)
```

For decimals and negatives:

```
not all(str(s).strip('-').replace('.','').isdigit() for s in a)
```

Comment: This will fail on ints and strings of negative numbers

Answer (score 3):

```
a = ['111', 213, 74, '99', 't', '88']

print([x for x in a if not str(x).isdigit()])

['t']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
a = ['111', 213, 74, '99', 't', '88']

def detect(list_):
    try:
        map(int,list_)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

print detect(a)
```

Comment: It's not a good idea. It just replaces `for` with `map`.